# What does prime mean in haskell?

Tags: haskell

In haskell I can see a lot of prime just like 'chainl1'

what does it mean?

```
  expr    = term   `chainl1` addop
  term    = factor `chainl1` mulop
  factor  = parens expr <|> integer

  mulop   =   do{ symbol "*"; return (*)   }
          <|> do{ symbol "/"; return (div) }

  addop   =   do{ symbol "+"; return (+) }
          <|> do{ symbol "-"; return (-) }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "prime"?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The prime (`'`) is treated like any number in variable names, i.e. unless it's at the beginning you can use it just like a letter. Hence names such as `foldl'`; generally those will refer some kind of "alternative" of a similar thing, in this case `foldl` which is equivalent except for lazy evaluation.

However, there aren't actually any primes in your examples. Those are *backticks*. Surrounding a function with backticks lets you use it like an infix operator, e.g.

```
plus :: Int -> Int -> Int
plus = (+)
```

> Prelude> 4 `plus` 5
>   9

Answer (score 6):

A binary function `f` is usually applied to 2 arguments as `f x y`. However, there are certain binary functions (like `elem`) for which it makes sense to see them infix and not postfix. To move a binary function to infix notation one encloses it in backticks (`` ` ``). Compare

```
intersect set1 set2 = [x | x <- set1, elem x set2]
```

with

```
intersect set1 set2 = [x | x<- set1, x `elem` set2]
```

The second one is closer to the mathematical notation.

See also [the corresponding learn you a Haskell chapter](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out)

PS: You can do the reverse for operators. Usually an operator is infix (`2 + 3`) but you can move it to prefix by enclosing it in parens (`(+) 2 3`)